# Formula help for matching data from multiple columns in multiple worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

What formula do I need in my worksheet `DFW` column `C` that will do the following?:

On worksheet `DFW` take data from cells `A2` together with `B2` and see if there is an exact match in worksheet `Feb` columns `A` and `B` - if there is, return a `Y` in `DFW` cell `C2`.

It does not necessarily need to be a “Y” in `DFW` column `C` – it could be  `1` for `Y` and `0` for `N`, as long as it is not an error.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for if I am reading the question right:

```
= IF (AND(DFW!A2 = Feb!A2, DFW!B2 = Feb!B2), "Y", "N")
```

It tests if cell A2 on the DFW worksheet matches cell A2 on the Feb worksheet and if the same is true for the two B2 cells return "Y" otherwise "N".

Updated answer based on comments:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(DFW!A2, Feb!A2:Feb!A5000, 0)), "N",  IF(DFW!B2 = LOOKUP(DFW!A2, Feb!A2:Feb!A50, Feb!B2:Feb!B5000), "Y", "N"))
```

This searches if DFW!A2 matches anything row in the A column on the Feb sheet. If not return "N". If there is a match on A it then checks B2 vs the corresponding row that was matched on A.

Comment: It is close to what I want except that I need it to search all of columns A & B in worksheet Feb like this: = IF (AND(DFW!A2 = Feb!A2:A5000, DFW!B2 = Feb!B2:B5000), "Y", "N")

Comment: Do you mean if the text in DFW!A2 matches any text in column A?

Comment: yes - so lets say it finds a match for DFW!A2 in Feb!A16 then I need to know if the text from DFW!B2 matches the text in Feb!B16 - if BOTH match in same row that is when i need the formula to return a Y in DFW!C2.

Comment: Updated the answer based on your latest comment

Comment: Brad your updated answer works except that I need to lock the cells in Columns A & B for worksheet Feb so that they dont roll up when the formula is copied down column C in worksheet DFW - when I do this using the $ to lock the cells the formula works if there is no match and returns a "N" but if there is a match it returns a "#N/A" instead of a "Y". Not sure why it does that??

Comment: Post the modified formula and I will take a look.

Comment: =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(DFW!A3, Feb!$A$2:Feb!$A$19, 0)), "N", IF(DFW!B3 = LOOKUP(DFW!A3, Feb!$A$2:Feb!$A$19, Feb!$B$2:Feb!$B$19), "Y", "N"))

Comment: When I run error checker it indicates that there is a problem with the "lookup" section of the formula

Comment: It seems to work fine for me even with the $'s. What version of Excel are you using? I am using 2010.

Comment: I am using 2007

Comment: I'm sorry i don't have a copy of 2007 to test with. You could try breaking the formula up into parts in different cells to try and identify the problem (eg put MATCH in one cell, LOOKUP in another)

Answer (score 0):

The catch with trying to deal with the columns individually is that MATCH with match_type 1 or -1 is not exact and with 0 only finds the *first* value that is exactly equal (I'm guessing you may have multiple instances). However the formula below may work for you (it is difficult to tell without sample data):

`=IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2&","&B2,Range,1,FALSE),"N")="N","N","Y")`

**provided** you are prepared to add a column to your Feb sheet with a formula in the top row of `=A1&","&B1` copied down to the end (this column I have named Range).

There may well be a better way (eg an array formula) but I have not bothered to try to optimise this as I am not at all sure it meets your requirements.